# Update specific R package from local source

Tags: r

I have R installed on a machine without internet access. Is it possible to update a specific package from a local source archive? What would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
install.packages(pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"),
                 contriburl = contrib.url(repos, type),
                 method, available = NULL, destdir = NULL,
                 dependencies = NA, type = getOption("pkgType"),
                 configure.args = getOption("configure.args"),
                 configure.vars = getOption("configure.vars"),
                 clean = FALSE, Ncpus = getOption("Ncpus", 1L),
                 verbose = getOption("verbose"),
                 libs_only = FALSE, INSTALL_opts, quiet = FALSE,
                 keep_outputs = FALSE, ...)
```

Use above command. for more help refer https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html

For updating: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/update.packages.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this command good for updating? Do I have to uninstall the previous version of the package?

Comment: `update.packages()` command would definitely help to install without uninstalling the previous version of packages.